# How do I subset a list in R by every 3 indices?

Tags: r, list, indexing, subset

I have a `list` which has 500 elements, but I want to get every 3rd element and save it to a variable. So I'd want `list[1]`, `list[4]`, `list[7]`, `list[10]` and etc saved to one variable.

I tried `sub.list <- list[1:500, by = 3]` but this doesn't work.

Comment: `1:500` is shorthand for `seq(1, 500, by = 1)` and `:` is a binary operator, so you cannot pass a third argument (`b = 3`) to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
L <- as.list(1:500) # create a list

L[seq(1, length(L), 3)]
# or, use recycling
L[c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
   sub.list<-myList[seq_along(myList)%%3==1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Filter:

```
L <- as.list(1:500) # create a list
Filter(function(i) {i %% 3 == 1},seq_along(L))
```

But won't work if you have NA's.

Comment: This would fail to capture any list elements that are  `NA`. For example, compare your result of `L <- as.list(c(1:3, NA, 5:7))` to the other answers.